# How to bind data to gridview by condition SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to create a stored procedure to bind employee data to gridview1 and edit by detailview1 in VB asp.net.

First in page load it will load all employees with `AllowPaging = true`.

Second when I submit search button `@employeename` from textbox and the gridview1 will show search result.

But my stored procedure can not work correctly. I only show data after input to textbox search.

Thanks,

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEmployee] 
    @EmployeeName NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@EmployeeName = 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            [EmployeeID], 
            [EmployeeCode], 
            [EmployeeName], 
            [Position], 
            [HireDate], 
        FROM 
            [Employee];
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            [EmployeeID], 
            [EmployeeCode], 
            [EmployeeName], 
            [Position], 
            [HireDate], 
        FROM 
            [Employee]
        WHERE
            ([EmployeeName] LIKE '%' + @EmployeeName + '%');
    END;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[GetEmployee] 
 @EmployeeName NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN       
        SELECT [EmployeeID], 
               [EmployeeCode], 
               [EmployeeName], 
               [Position],  [HireDate], 
        FROM [Employee] WHERE(ISNULL(@EmployeeName,'')='' OR [EmployeeName] LIKE '%' + @EmployeeName+'%');
END
```

Comment: Thank for your guide, But It not works with my case, It can not run in page load event,